# PHP Install Failure With wampserver2

Tags: php, windows, apache2, wamp, wampserver

I installed wampserver 2.2e (php5.4.3 / apache 2.2.22) on my Windows 2003 machine, and get this error in the system event logs:

> Generate Activation Context failed for C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\php5apache2_2.dll. Reference error message: The referenced assembly is not installed on your system.

The DLL in question does exist in the folder specified.

**Update**: VC10 SP1 (32-bit) was installed prior to wamp.

I previously had tried to install apache and php manually, and encountered issues with apache loading the php5 module correctly as well. I assumed that WAMP would work fine (it has on all other instances when I have installed). I did have an earlier version of both apache and php working on this machine.

Now I'm not so sure it's the install, but something with Windows?

**Update 2**: In the system event logs, I noticed this error each time I try to run wamp. I looks related as it is referencing VC9, but the website says to install VC10:

> Dependent Assembly Microsoft.VC90.CRT could not be found and Last Error was The referenced assembly is not installed on your system.

Comment: Have you checked to make sure that php5apache2_2.dll is actually in that directory? (C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\)?

Comment: Yes, it is. I'll update the post with this info, too.

Comment: A big suggestion to you: Use linux to host PHP webservers. If you cannot host a linux box, use virtualisation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the Microsoft Visual Studio C++ Redistributable Package. [LINK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5555) This link is for the 2010 version. Check the PHP documentation, you may need an older version.

Comment: I checked and it was already on there. Let me update the post.

Comment: Well, this sounds like it is a reboot problem or something did not get installed properly. I assume you have rebooted after installing the components - So, I would suggest uninstall the Redis. package and WAMP, then Reinstall Redis. package and WAMP again to see if that fixes it.

Comment: Another idea I just thought of is if there were multiple versions of the C++ Redis. package installed on the system. If that is the case, I would remove all of them and install just the newest version.

Comment: I deleted VC 2005 and wampserver, rebooted, then installed VC 10, then Wampserver 2. Same error.

Comment: Based on your edit - Maybe try this: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26368 It includes VC90.CRT

Comment: That did it! I had VC 2005 and 2010 installed, but apparently it needed VC 2008 as well.

Comment: Good deal. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

Taken directly from WAMP website:

> WARNING : You must install Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package
>   x86 or x64 VC10 SP1 vcredist_x86.exe 32 bits :
>   http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=8328 VC10 SP1
>   vcredist_x64.exe 64 bits :
>   http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=13523

Comment: VC 2010 x86 (vcredist_x86) was installed already, before wamp.

Comment: This error message always came from this kind of problem. Maybe try a reinstall of the package? Double check if you wouldn't need the x64 version instead?

Comment: I don't see a 64-bit version of VC10 working on a 32-bit version of Windows.

Comment: Me neither, I just don't see where you state that you have a 32-bit windows, this is why I said that...

Comment: My apologies! I thought I had that stated that piece of info.

Answer (score 1):

You also need [Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=5582)

The 2010 VC redist is for Apache.

The 2008 redist is for Wampmanager.